# ASP.NET Web API Action Results

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

When we use a `HttpGet` action method to get resources we generally return `Ok()`.

```
public IHttpActionResult Get() {
  var customers = context.customers.toList();
  return Ok(customers);
}
```

When we use `HttpPost` action method to create a record we return **Created()** with the location of the newly created resource.

When we use `HttpPut` to update a record what do we return? For example when we read records we return `Ok()` and for create we return `Created()`

And also what do we return for `HttpDelete`?

Comment: Status 200 (Ok) is probably fine for both. If you return anything with it (content) depends on what the consumer/requester needs.

Comment: I've read that for HttpPut and HttpDelete requests the return type of the method is generally void..so then we dont use a return in the method body..Is this approach widely used??

Comment: I believe if you do that and no exception occurs the status 204 (no content) is still returned to the client by the framework so it knows the call succeeded (as far as it knows). So `void` is also fine or `async Task` if there there are async methods being called.

Comment: Thankyou...That clears the confusion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According the tutorial in https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/tutorials/first-web-api.html, when you execute an `HTTP PUT` or `HTTP DELETE` you must return `204 (No content)` code.

```
return new NoContentResult();
```

Comment: My fault, link fixed.